# nginx rewrite module not working?

Tags: nginx

I have the nginx.conf to fuelphp

```
location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 last;
    }
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass   unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    include        fastcgi.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
```

but this not working with   testfphp/public/welcome/hello

the nginx says: file not found

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have mixed different bits from different how-to's, without understanding them. Observe:

```
rewrite ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 last; #question mark, typo?
location ~ \.php$ # matches end of request_uri
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$; # matches .php followed by a slash
```

For the third statement to match, `.php` is never at end of request_uri, so this statement will never match in this location.

Remove the question mark from the first statement, remove the dollar sign from the location. Then add:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$ fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_split_pathinfo;
```

to the location block. Try to understand from the documentation and try to further restrict the location block.